# How do I get the filename without the params?

Tags: php, filenames

I need to find the file name of the file I've included without the GET parameters.

e.g.: 
if the current URL is http://www.mysite.com/folder/file.php?a=b&c=d ,
i want file.php returned

what I have found:

```
basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])
```

which returns:

```
file.php?a=b&c=d
```

in my case:
I'm using the filename in a form in the section for my cart, so at the moment each time you click the 'reduce number of product' button it adds the GET params of the form (productId and action) to the end of the URL:
file.php?a=b&c=d?a=b&c=d?a=b&c=d?a=b&c=d...

I know I could simply explode or something similar on '?'

```
$file = explode("?", basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']))
```

and use the first part of the array, but I seem to recall something easier, however cannot locate the code again..

I'm new to PHP so explanation on your code would be appreciated.

Thanks,
V

Answer (score 14):

You can make use of [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php). In your case you could use:

```
$url = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
```

To get only the file name you can do something like this:

```
$url = explode('/', parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH));
$url = end($url);
```

Comment: This is the closest I've found.  Here's how I did it:$url = parse_url($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], PHP_URL_PATH);
$url = explode('/', parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH));
$url = end($url);
error_log($url);

Answer (score 10):

Maybe you are looking for `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`.

Please notice that it has a '/' char in the beginning.

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried a simple `basename(__FILE__);`? This will get you the filename of where the code is located, as it is on disk.

For getting the requested file, you can use `basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);`. This will always get the file that was requested, rather than the file that the code is contained within.

Comment: Yes, I've tried and noticed that it won't work if the file you want is included.
(My bad, should've mentioned that in the post)

Comment: Ah sorry, in that case you could **try** `basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'])`? EDIT: Actually you could even just do `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']`, as far as I know it doesn't contain any path info.

Comment: $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] does it! Thanks!

Comment: No problem! Also, ignore my edit, it appears that `SCRIPT_FILENAME` is an alias of `SCRIPT_NAME` thus contains the full path.

Comment: SCRIPT_NAME is the actual script after rewrite (typicall ends on .php), REQUEST_URI is as-shown-in-browser-bar. Both may bear GET parameters.

Comment: REQUEST_URI will contain GET parameters, SCRIPT_NAME will not do so as GET parameters do not constitute, well, a script's name.

Answer (score 4):

```
basename(parse_url($url,PHP_URL_PATH));
```

parse_url($url,PHP_URL_PATH) erase params.
basename() get filename of path.

Answer (score 2):

```
basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
```

This will do it.

In addition it is always good to know some given variables. The following snippet in a php file is really useful.

```
<pre><?php
print_r($_SERVER);
?></pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

The best solution for me:

```
$file = basename(parse_url($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], PHP_URL_PATH));
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at some of the other values in `$_SERVER`.

Maybe `$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]` or `$_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"]` will return what you want.

Answer (score 0):

This is the closest I've found. Here's how I did it:

```
$url = parse_url($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], PHP_URL_PATH);
$url = explode('/', parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH));
$url = end($url);
error_log($url);
```

Answer (score -1):

The only way that you get the name of the script without the parameters is making a POST request

Comment: All of the people above have shown that's clearly not the case.