# getting part of string

Tags: php, regex

What is best practice to get 
**584ef6a14e69e**
out of string `/files/028ou2p5g/blogs/70cw99r5k/584ef6a14e69e-120.jpg`
?

Assume all data is not constant. I need symbols after last slash and before minus sign.

Comment: `parse_url()` could most likely do this as an alternate to regex. I.e.: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5870133/1415724 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/19644313/1415724

Comment: What is consistent about the string?

Comment: Seems like you already asked something similar http://stackoverflow.com/q/41036804/1415724 but the question wasn't marked as solved. This seems like a duplicate question to me.

Comment: and now someone popped an answer; so... comments?

Comment: Fred that topic didn't gave me the full answer I'll delete it and concentrate on this one.

Comment: You misphrased your intentions there like you did here. The question you asked there `I want to find FIRST such tag, and get image name from it 5844644f69fe7-64.jpg` was answered. Here's a hint though look at greedy and non-greedy regexs. Then be greedy until your `/` and then non-greedy till the `-`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the proper tools so that there is no guesswork.  This gets the filename without extension and then everything before the `-`:

```
$string = '/files/028ou2p5g/blogs/70cw99r5k/584ef6a14e69e-120.jpg';
$result = strstr(pathinfo($string, PATHINFO_FILENAME), '-', true);
```

Or slightly shorter:

```
$result = strstr(basename($string), '-', true);
```

Comment: Wow that's even better. But I've already gave solved solution to Andrew. sorry. Gave u plus! And many thanks!

Comment: Done :)
by the way what's the best practice of getting extension from that string ?
is there anything like basename() ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it will always be `-120.jpg` and the part you want to get is composed of a-z and 0-9 characters, you may do as follow (using regex):

```
<?php

preg_match(
    '/([a-z0-9]+)-120\.jpg$/',
    '/files/028ou2p5g/blogs/70cw99r5k/584ef6a14e69e-120.jpg',
    $matches
);

var_dump($matches[1]);
```

otherwise, if always a number:

```
<?php

preg_match(
    '/([a-z0-9]+)-[0-9]+\.jpg$/',
    '/files/028ou2p5g/blogs/70cw99r5k/584ef6a14e69e-120.jpg',
    $matches
);

var_dump($matches[1]);
```

you may want to play more with **regex** in order to do something fitting more your needs (testing the length, case sensitivity, place in the string...)

Comment: What about if everything is changeble ? I mean I want only symbols after last slash and before minus sign.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$string = '/files/028ou2p5g/blogs/70cw99r5k/584ef6a14e69e-120.jpg';
$string = basename($string);

// remove all characters after and including '-' if it exists in string
$pos = strpos($string, '-');
if ($pos !== false)
    $string = substr($string, 0, $pos);

echo $string; // outputs: 584ef6a14e69e

?>
```

Comment: strange , but it gave me just what I wanted 584ef6a14e69e without -120 :)

Comment: He seems to have a standard on his filename, so if it exists at all time it won't be an issue. But sure, I'll add some extra safety.

Comment: Should be better now?

Comment: good, but when I told u that it gave just what I wanted I was satisfied :) I have standard of '-' sign. So your solution is perfect. Thanks!